# Gnome issue with app windows showing content on the background

Tags: gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 on a dual display setup and I'm getting this annoying issue of app windows showing the content that is behind them. This is more frequent when more apps / windows are open at the same time. Here I'm using Eclipse, a Terminal and Spotify and you can see a part of the IDE and some desktop icons bleeding through the Chrome Browser which is on top.[image]

This is somewhat annoying in some apps...is there any workaround available?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be an issue with your graphics drivers/configuration. You will need to post system information.

Comment: What kind of info?

Comment: Computer, type of graphics card. You may be using open source drives and might have better results with proprietary drivers or vice versa. If graphics are the issue, your specific hardware matters.